# Conditions for water to go down from high places

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow

- I've noticed that all of the above-ceiling water tanks are piped in a
  way that ensures to be open to the air at the tank, and then these   water-carrying pipes go down to the kitchen or rest rooms,..etc

I mean that water won't flow in the kitchen's nor toilet's pipes without being open to the atmosphere at the tank position.. Why is that?

I need a scientific explanation accounting for this phenomenon.. any general formula is welcome..

Answer (score 0):

If air cannot enter the tank as water runs out, then a partial vacuum will form in the tank. Once the vacuum pressure equals the pull of gravity on the water it will no longer flow.

Comment: Do you have any formula supporting this answer?

Comment: It's the basic formula for hydrostatic pressure: $P = \rho g h$. Google for how a barometer works, to see what happens if the building is more than 10 meters (30 feet) high.